# Cant install Numpy+MKL

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

1. I have win10, x64, i7-3770K

   2. I downloaded  numpy-1.11.0+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl  from the 
      http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
   3. I have python 3.5 installed from the official cite
   4. i have latest version of pip
      when I do pip3.5 install "mydir"\numpy-1.11.0+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl i get this errors

   Exception:
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 209, in main
       status = self.run(options, args)
     File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 299, in run
       requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
     File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 360, in prepare_files
       ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
     File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 577, in _prepare_file
       session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
     File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 798, in unpack_url
       unpack_file_url(link, location, download_dir, hashes=hashes)
     File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 705, in unpack_file_url
       unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
     File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\utils__init__.py", line 599, in unpack_file
       flatten=not filename.endswith('.whl')
     File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\utils__init__.py", line 484, in unzip_file
       zip = zipfile.ZipFile(zipfp, allowZip64=True)
     File "d:\python\lib\zipfile.py", line 1026, in **init**
       self._RealGetContents()
     File "d:\python\lib\zipfile.py", line 1093, in _RealGetContents
       raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
   zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

Comment: Maybe it's easier to download the Anaconda distribution from https://www.continuum.io/downloads . It has most important packages and a nice editor (Spyder). I've had a lot of trouble installing packages on Windows with the standard Python distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I have met the same problem as yours. It's pretty simple.

The .whl file is Packaged by zip. So I check the file of *.whl and found it has a wrong size. A problem occurred when downloading the file.

So try to download it again!

Answer (score 0):

Using Windows Power Shell, upgrade pip and then try installing the numpy whl again. It just worked for me .. worth a shot !

Answer (score 0):

Just re-download the `Numpy+MKL` file. The reason is `.whl` file is a `zip` file so if Bzip cannot unzip this file maybe you have a problem with your `.whl` file. Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the version of Python whether it is working in 64  bit or 32 bit mode  because this 64/32 bit of python is not related to  the X64 bit of your laptop.   And the .whl file that you would like to install should be   amd64.whl if the python working mode is 64 bit